# 50's movie where an alien invasion implants devices into human heads for mind control

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I'm looking for a 1950's movie where there was an alien invasion. They sent mechanical bat-like objects flying around implanting little devices into human heads, and then taking control of their minds.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Possibly "[It Conquered the World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_Conquered_the_World)" (1956).  It has the bat thingies but there's only one alien.

Comment: I've seen the Mystery Science Theater 3000 version of this, and t sounds like what the question is looking for, but see my comment on _Zontar, the Thing From Venus_.

Answer (score 2):

The movie you are looking for is [**Invaders from Mars**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Mars_%281953_film%29).

Comment: How do you know that?  Can you explain how the movies are the same?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it is "Zontar the Thing from Venus." Zontar was a bat-like alien who lived 
in a cave and grew little bat-like things that flew through the air chasing people 
and implanting what looks like barbed wire in their necks, after which he would be able to control them for the purpose of conquering Earth.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "In 1966, It Conquered the World was remade in 16mm color by self-proclaimed "schlockmeister" Larry Buchanan after he secured rights from AIP; he retitled his rewritten remake Zontar, the Thing from Venus and then sold it to television syndication."